# How to publish Umbraco from Visual Studio without getting the install wizard

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, umbraco

I have set up a new project in Visual Studio 2012 to do some development on Umbraco. I am running Umbraco 7.0.0

When I publish to my staging server the first time, everything goes as expected, the site loads, I get the installation wizard and all is well.

Now when I make changes to some of the files I have created in VS2012 (not touching the core files) and I publish again it "resets" my previous Umbraco installation and forces me to go through the installation wizard again..

Is there any way around this?

EDIT: Ok so it seems the actual installation wizard will auto perform an "upgrade" when publishing to an existing database, yet I want to skip this step alltogether.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the value of umbracoConfigurationStatus is not empty in the web.config after the deploy or else it will run the installion wizard

Comment: Thanks, will try that tomorrow and let you know how I go!

Comment: Thanks! Just had a look and the value you refer to sits in the appsettings.config, yet when I put in the value that is the same as the server it throws an "Object not set as a reference of an object" error when I try to load the pages after a publish, any ideas?